# Como hacer scraping de un archivo xml remoto?

Tags: javascript, xml, datos-abiertos

Quiero obtener ciertos datos de un archivo XML de libre acceso en un servidor remoto.

Se trata de archivos de Datos Abiertos de AEMET. La idea es leer el xml y extraer cierta información. 
Quiero hacerlo utilizando javascript, de manera que pueda visualizar en una web estos datos obtenidos del archivo xml. 
Como ejemplo uno de los archivos es;

http://www.aemet.es/xml/maritima/FQXX46MM.xml

Entiendo como hacerlo en Python; creo una variable con el contenido del XML y después con BeautifulSoup o cualquier otro scrapper leo los datos DOM del xml. 
No tengo ni idea de cómo comenzar en javascritp. ¿Como leo el xml remoto? a partir de ahí creo que entiendo cómo puedo obtener los datos de cada etiqueta.

He buscado como hacerlo y todo lo que encuentro parece orientado a Ajax, pero no acabo de encontrar como hacerlo leyendo directamente el xml remoto.

Comment: Ejecuta una petición contra ese servidor. Captura la respuesta en una variable que tendrá el contenido XML y luego lo parseas. ¿Cuál es el problema concreto?

Comment: No se como 'ejecutar la petición contra el servidor'

Comment: ¿Algo como `$.get("http://www.aemet.es/xml/maritima/FQXX46MM.xml", function (data) { console.log(data); })` de jquery?

Comment: Solo usa una llamada a ajax con el framework de tu elección jQuery, Angular, Javascript puro, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes especificar el `dataType` de la función $.ajax de jQuery como "xml"

Ejemplo

```js
$("button").click(function(){
     
    $.get({
        url: "http://www.aemet.es/xml/maritima/FQXX46MM.xml",
        dataType: "xml"
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        // Has algo con la variable data
        alert(data);
    })
    .error(function(e){
        //Desafortunadamente el recurso XML al estar en otro dominio no permite ser obtenido por AJAX al no tener el header: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
        alert(e.statusText);
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Prueba ajax con xml</button>
```

Desafortunadamente como indica el comentario, el recurso en particular al que tratas de acceder: http://www.aemet.es/xml/maritima/FQXX46MM.xml no entrega en el response el header `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin"` por lo que el navegador bloqueará el request mostrando el siguiente mensaje (en Chrome):

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.aemet.es/xml/maritima/FQXX46MM.xml. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Así que, al menos a ese archivo en particular no lo podrás leer desde JavaScript, a menos que esa página liste el dominio donde está alojado tu script como permitido.

Comment: Ahora ya lo voy viendo. Gracias

Comment: He conseguido hacerlo de otra forma; utilizando xReader.